# Why is there a difference in text length with backspace or delete (in TinyMCE)

Tags: javascript, count, tinymce, backspace

In my TinyMCE.init method, I have a setup function like this one :

```
setup: function(ed){
    ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e){
        var count = ed.getBody().innerText.length;
        var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
        console.log(count);
        console.log(ed.getBody().innerText);
    });
}
```

If my textarea is empty, when I press Backspace (key = 8), count equals 0.
When I press Delete (key = 46), count equals 1.

In both cases, `console.log(ed.getBody().innerText);` returns an empty string.

I want to use this to count (and limit) the size of my TinyMCE.
Does anyone can illuminate me about that strange difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Delete` is character code 127 in the ASCII-Table. The delete char is written into the textinput and therefore counts to the length of it, but is not displayed, because control characters dont get displayed.

This is indeed strange behaviour, because actually the delete character should not be written into the text field, but it seems like it does

Comment: It was not a code 127 but a code 10... Anyway, you pointed the solution !

Comment: Code 10 is the newline, which should even less appear when you type delete :D